# Firebase Event Occurrences for New Installed Users in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Given the install date of users, I would like to get the Firebase (1) **Event Occurrences** and (2) **Event Distinct Users' Count** for all our 200+ Firebase events on Day0 to Day30. I simulated the output table below (for D0-D30) in a screenshot, but the code is only for Day0-Day7.

**(1) Event Occurrences**

[image]

```
SELECT
  event.name as event_name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170801' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170802' THEN event_count END) AS D0_USERS,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170802' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170803' THEN event_count END) AS D1_USERS,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170803' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170804' THEN event_count END) AS D2_USERS,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170804' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170805' THEN event_count END) AS D3_USERS,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170805' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170806' THEN event_count END) AS D4_USERS,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170806' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170807' THEN event_count END) AS D5_USERS,  
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170807' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170808' THEN event_count END) AS D6_USERS,  
  COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170808' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170809' THEN event_count END) AS D7_USERS    
FROM `<<project-id>>.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170801' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170809' AND
  user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros BETWEEN 1501545600000000 AND 1501632000000000;
```

and

**(2) Event Distinct Users' Count**

[image]

```
SELECT
  event.name as event_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170801' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170802' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D0_USERS,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170802' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170803' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D1_USERS,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170803' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170804' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D2_USERS,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170804' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170805' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D3_USERS,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170805' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170806' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D4_USERS,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170806' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170807' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D5_USERS,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170807' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170808' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D6_USERS,  
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170808' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170809' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS D7_USERS    
FROM `<<project-id>>.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170801' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170809'
  AND user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros BETWEEN 1501545600000000 AND 1501632000000000
GROUP BY 1;
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a more optimised way to write this? For small amount of columns it makes sense (D0-D7), but for D0-D30 I thought there might be a better way. Any suggestions are much appreciated !

**Final Answer after Mikhail's feedback:**

I combined both queries in one query and created a pivot table thereafter. Remember to select "Standard SQL" in BigQuery editor before execution.

```
SELECT
  event.name AS event_name,
  _TABLE_SUFFIX as day,
  COUNT(1) as event_occurances,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as event_unique_users
FROM `<<project-id>>.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170801' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170901' AND
  user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros BETWEEN 1501545600000000 AND 1501632000000000
GROUP BY event_name, day
ORDER BY event_name;
```

**Appendix Notes:**

Timestamp Conversion of 1 Aug 2017

- Epoch timestamp: 1501545600
- Timestamp in milliseconds: 1501545600000

Timestamp Conversion of 2 Aug 2017

- Epoch timestamp: 1501632000
- Timestamp in milliseconds: 1501632000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more optimised way to write this?

**1**. One way to optimize this is to rewrite below

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170801' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170802' THEN event_count END) AS D0_USERS
```

to this

```
COUNTIF(_TABLE_SUFFIX = '20170801') AS D0_USERS
```

:o( You still will need to write this line 31 times for the D0-D30 case, but at least it is less heavy

**2**. Another (proper) way is to follow best practices and separate retrieval of data from data visualization

So you can do something like below to retrieve needed data

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event.name AS event_name,
  _TABLE_SUFFIX as day,
  COUNT(1) as users
FROM `<<project-id>>.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170801' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170809' AND
  user_dim.first_open_timestamp_micros BETWEEN 1501545600000000 AND 1501632000000000
GROUP BY event_name, day
```

Then you can pivot this result with whatever tool you prefer

For example, with [BigQuery Mate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) without leaving UI you can get pivot that will look like below

[image]

*As a quick disclosure - I am an author of the BigQuery Mate Chrome Extension*

Please note: I have not adjusted or changed anyhow logic of your query - i just answered your specific question - Is there a more optimised way to write this?

Comment: Super! Thanks again Mikhail, I have made a note to download Mate and play with it! Ps: Above "User Progression Model" I have been working on is essentially an evolution from User Retention (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767982/calculating-in-app-purchaser-retention-cohorts-in-firebase-bigquery). I thought it would be good to share it here and hope more people could find it beneficial :)